# Need a "picture" of the Mountain Pass Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm looking at Ambrosetti and Rabinowitz's paper "Dual variational methods in critical point theory and applications" as in this link [Mountain Pass Theorem](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123673900517). Theorem 2.1 in the paper is just the Mountain Pass Theorem in an infinite dimensional case, which I can find in other sources.

The picture that I have in mind for Theorem 2.1 is that for a path connecting $0$ and $e$ ($2$ valleys), we can find the highest point (on the mountain range). Then among all such paths, we find the one with the smallest height. This point is the critical point (saddle point).

The authors present Theorem 2.4 as the dual of Theorem 2.1 by interchanging the order of $\inf \sup$ taking over appropriate sets.

1) Could someone please explain to me the picture for this theorem? It is hard to imagine.

2) Why is the critical point in Theorem 2.4 can be strictly less than the one in Theorem 2.1? What is a (simple, non-trivial) example (preferred in 1-d)?

Thank you very much.

Comment: One way that $c \ne b$ is if there is a trough surrounding $0$ whose elevation is below $0$, outside of which is a ring whose elevation exceeds anything inside the trough, and finally $e$ on the other side of the ring. Since you cannot get to $e$ without crossing the ring, $b$ is at least as high as the ring. But the hypersurfaces defining $c$ must have everything inside with positive elevation, so they cannot extend past the trough. Therefore $c$ will be inside the trough, where the elevation is strictly less than the ring, which is in turn $\le b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a swing at the first one.

Since $h$ is a homeomorphism fixing $0$, $h(S)$ is a closed "hypersurface" surrounding $0$. Further the set $\Gamma_*^e$ consists of only homeomorphisms with $0$ and $e$ on opposite sides of $h(S)$, so the only way to get from one to the other is through $h(S)$. And further, the condition $h(B) \subset \hat A_0$ just means that $I(h(v)) \ge 0$ when $v$ is inside (on the same side as $0$) of $h(S)$.

So, intuitively, $h(B)$ is some blob around $0$ where all elevations $I$ are greater than or equal to the elevation at $0$, and such that $e$ is a point of the same elevation as $0$ but outside the blob. $$\inf_{u \in S} I(h(u))$$ is the lowest elevation anywhere on the boundary of this blob.
$$\sup_{h \in \Gamma_*^e} \inf_{u \in S} I(h(u))$$ is then the highest low point on the boundaries of any such blob.

So, in the two-dimensional terrain concept, plot $0$ and $e$ on a map. They happen to have the same elevation. Further, $0$ is at the bottom of a local depression. Start drawing simple closes curves around $0$, avoiding any location where the elevation is actually lower than at $0$, and keeping $e$ on the opposite side of the curves from $0$. For each such curve, note the lowest elevation on it. Choose the curve $C$ with the highest "low elevation", and let $c$ be the location of the lowest elevation along $C$. (Note that I am varying somewhat from the notation in the paper, where $c$ is the elevation, not the location where it occurs). Now if we follow $C$ away from $c$, we can only go up. If we leave $c$ transversely to $C$, we have to be going down, or else we could modify $C$ in that direction to get one with a higher low point. So $c$ must be a saddle point.

The path $P$ from $0$ to $e$ on which the point $b$ from the Mountain pass theorem lies has to cross $C$ somewhere. Call that point $p$. Since every point on $C$ is at least as high as $c$, the elevation at $p$ is the same or higher than that at $c$. Since $b$ is the highest point along $P$, the elevation at $b$ is at least as high as at $p$. So
$$I(b) \ge I(p) \ge I(c)$$

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. Can you think of a specific function in $\mathbb{R}$ where we have a strict inequality?

Comment: [$y=x\sin x$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+x+sin+x+from+-10+to+10), with $e = 3\pi$. The largest blob that stays above 0 extends out to $\pi$. The "simple closed curves" are pairs of points, and obviously the one with the highest low point is at $x \approx 2$ with height $c \approx 1.82$. But to get to $3\pi$, you have to pass over the second higher hump at $x\approx 7.98$ and height $b \approx 7.92$.

Comment: I appreciate so much for your help.

Comment: As far as I can see, the only reason to require $I(h(u)) \ge 0$ on $B$ is that occasionally it finds $c < b$. If you drop that requirement, then I think it likely that the value of $c$ it finds would be exactly $b$.